# Number Format from Crystal-Reports to Excel (commas becoming dots)

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, formatting

When I export my report to Excel, the format changes.

Commas turns to dots.

Example:
(In Crystal report)
537,37

(Exported in Excel)
537.37

Is there a workaround to keep the comma from translating into a dot ?

Comment: If your system's regional settings use a comma as a decimal point then this 'feature' may be hard-coded into CR's export routine and you need to change the number format in Excel.

Comment: I can't change the regional setting on the user workstations so how can I hard-code it?  ToText the numbers ?  I've tried a number of ways and they all come up with errors.

Comment: range.replace? range.numberformat? I dunno. You haven't provided anywhere near enough information to even hazard a guess.

Comment: I,ve got two columns I'm trying to export to excel from Crystal report.   Regional Setting is not an option but I can do whatever I want in Crystal Report, not in Excel.   It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: toText({numbertoexport},2,"",",")  
I tried this.  It's very simple but it comes out with "boolean value expected" and I realy don't get why.   It's pretty simple!